# MySql tables, creating new

Tags: mysql, database, datatables

it seems like my syntax for the following command is incorrect. The error message points to the default current timestamp. Can someone point out where am I going wrong? Your help is much appreciated as I'm working on my first app. My code is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
ingredient VARCHAR(100),
created_at DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated_at DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: You didn't give `created_at` or `updated_at` a data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the Data Type ;)

The correct Query is following:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ingredient VARCHAR(100),
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Check out the docs: [MySQL Docs | Create Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

You can check your syntax with following tool: [SQL Validator](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/)